# Ef core many to many relationship inside a generic repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get work with many-to-many relationship in my web application. I am using a generic repository base code.

Here my the entities

```
public class UserEntity : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRoleEntity> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class RoleEntity : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRoleEntity> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserRoleEntity : BaseEntity<Guid>
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserEntity UserEntity { get; set; }
    public virtual RoleEntity RoleEntity { get; set; }
}
```

This is context model configuration

```
private void ConfigureUserRole(EntityTypeBuilder<UserRoleEntity> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("UserRole");

    //there is no need for a surrogate key on many-to-many mapping table
    builder.Ignore("Id");

    builder.HasKey(ur => new { ur.RoleId, ur.UserId });

    builder.HasOne(ur => ur.RoleEntity)
        .WithMany(r => r.Users)
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);

    builder.HasOne(ur => ur.UserEntity)
        .WithMany(u => u.UserRoles)
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
}
```

This is the main get method of  my generic repository (in fact it is [Chris Pratt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654031/chris-pratt)'s [implementation](https://cpratt.co/truly-generic-repository/)) Please notice the `query.Include` line, the get methods of generic repository make use of EF Core's `Include` api to get dependent entity which comes as string parameter .

```
 protected virtual IQueryable<T> GetQueryable(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
                                                    string includeProperties = null,
                                                    int? skip = null,
                                                    int? take = null)
        {
            includeProperties = includeProperties ?? string.Empty;
            IQueryable<T> query = _dbContext.Set<T>();

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }

            if (skip.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Skip(skip.Value);
            }

            if (take.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Take(take.Value);
            }

            return query;
        }
```

And in my service, I want to get user data with its full dependents.

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private IRepository<UserEntity> _userRepository;
    private IRepository<RoleEntity> _roleRepository;

    public UserService(IRepository<UserEntity> userRepository, IRepository<RoleEntity> roleRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }
    public UserEntity GetUserData(string employeeId)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.GetFirst(u => u.EmployeeId == employeeId, includeProperties: "UserRoles");
        //var roles = _roleRepository.GetAll().ToList();

        return user;
    }
}
```

When the above service code executed, I get the user with its `UserRole` dependent, however, when I inspect `UserRole`'s `RoleEntity` dependent which I need, it is `null`.

- How can I get the dependent `RoleEntity` data just modifying the generic repository's get method?
- Secondly, the line commented in service code (`_roleRepository.GetAll()`), when it is also executed, the `RoleEntity` is immediately filled with its proper value. How is it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your include path only  has a single hop from `UserEntity` to `UserRoleEntity` (via the `UserRoles` property. You need to include the next step to ensure you also capture the `RoleEntity`. To do this, change your path to `UserRoles.RoleEntity`, for example:

```
var user = _userRepository.GetFirst(
    u => u.EmployeeId == employeeId, 
    includeProperties: "UserRoles.RoleEntity");
```

Comment: Thank you @DavidG, I couldn't imagine it would be so easy, docs has nothing about this. For my second question, do you have any idea how that happens?

Comment: Your object hierarchy is User -> UserRole -> Role and you were only loading the middle part. If you were using the lambda version of the `Include` method, that may have been a bit clearer.

Comment: Yes I got it but I am asking that when I call the role data from db via its separate repository, how the `User.UserRole.RoleEntity` is filled up? Before that line `RoleEntity` is null but after that line executed then I inspect `RoleEntity`, it seems it is filled.

Comment: I think I have the answer of my second question from the tip inside [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading)